# Express and Passport Error: Unknown authentication strategy "login"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am currently running a simple test MEAN stack from an online tutorial utilizing:

- Node.js
- Express.js
- Passport.js

Here is the application file:

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var flash = require("connect-flash");
var ejs = require("ejs");

var routes = require("./routes");

var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb");

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(flash());

app.use(routes);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
    console.log("MEAN social media server started on port " + app.get("port"));
});
```

While there are views in this **app.js** file, the concentration here is for the route that is required with the **routes** variable:

**routes.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var passport = require("passport");

var User = require("./models/user");

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.errors = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.infos = req.flash("info");
    next();
});

router.get("/", function(req, res,next) {
    User.find()
        .sort({ createdAt: "descending" })
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.render("index", { users: users });
        });
});

router.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signup");
});

router.post("/signup", function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            req.flash("error", "User already exists");
            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }

        var newUser = new User({
            username: username,
            password: password
        });
        newUser.save(next);
    });
}, passport.authenticate("login", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/signup",
    failureFlash: true
}));

router.get("/users/:username", function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return next(404);
        }
        res.render("profile", {
            user: user
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the views/signup.ejs file:

**views/signup.ejs**

```
<% include _header %>

<h1>Sign up</h1>

<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control"     placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>

<% include _footer %>
```

When the submit button is clicked on the **views/signup.ejs** file, the 'User' records are indeed submitted to the MongoDB database, however after insertion the following error is rendered on the "/signup" post method:

**localhost:3000/signup (POST)**

```
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "login"
    at attempt     (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:166:37)
   at authenticate (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at model.<anonymous> (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1731:20)
   at next_ (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:89:34)
   at fnWrapper (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:295:13
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:230:5
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:139:7
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:479:5
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:633:5
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:469:9
   at resultHandler (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:416:5)
   at /<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:778:13
   at Callbacks.emit (/<APP_PATH>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
```

I did notice that there is no reference to the **"login"** event for the **passport.authenticate** function located in the **routes.js** file.

Anyone receive a similar "Error: Unknown authentication strategy "login"" error?

Comment: in router.js

`newUser.save(next);
    });
}, passport.authenticate("login",`

are you sure you can do this? I mean, putting 3 parameters in `router.post()`? 

You are doing

`router.post('/', function() , function() )`

Comment: Where is your Passport setup?

Comment: @Diego the issue here was I didn't create the "login" face (or view).

Comment: @robertklep the issue appeared to be the fact that the "login" view was not available. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would have elected to delete this question, but because I sincerely stayed up over night to fix this issue, I should at least post what the error was.

At the point of construction of this application, the following views were created:

- index.ejs
- signup.ejs

If you take a look at the **routes.js** file above, when a person posts the signup form (**router.post("/signup"**..), the passport.authenticate will send the user automatically registers the "login" view and send the user to the root endpoint.

The non existence of the called "login" state was causing the error, hence the following message:

**"Error: Unknown authentication strategy "login"" error**

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Passport is oblivious to views. The error you got has to do with how you register strategies with Passport, and I guess that you solved _that_ issue as well.

Comment: @robertklep technically, at the time of issue report, I had no strategy (later, I required "passport-local"), so that is definitely correct. After implementing a **passport.use("login",...** function, it did indeed work. Thanks for the clarification.